# Computing the gradient of least-squares cost

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, least-squares

Trying to understand the multivariable proof of the least square estimations.
I have difficulty differentiating the loss function with regards to $\vec{\beta}$.
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial L\left(D, \vec{\beta}\right)}{\partial\vec{\beta}}
    &= \frac{\partial \left(Y^\textsf{T}Y - Y^\textsf{T}X\vec{\beta} - \vec{\beta}^\textsf{T}X^\textsf{T}Y + \vec{\beta}^\textsf{T}X^\textsf{T}X\vec{\beta}\right)}{\partial \vec{\beta}} \\
    &= -2X^\textsf{T}Y + 2X^\textsf{T}X\vec{\beta}
\end{align}

I am stucked when we have to derive with regards to $\beta$ a term containing $\beta^T$. How should that deal be with ?

Comment: The given derivative uses the (in my view confusing) convention that the derivative is the transpose of the actual derivative. For the derivative of a vector w.r.t. to a vector you can use the following heuristic $$\frac{\partial \vec{f}(\vec{x},\vec{x}^T)}{\partial \vec{x}} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)_{\vec{x}^T} + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}^T}\right)_{\vec{x}}^T$$

Comment: Thanks, according to your heuristic, I would write that : $$\frac{ \partial (\beta^TX^TX\beta)}{\partial \beta} = \beta^T X^T X + X^TX\beta $$ but that's not equal to $ 2X^T X \beta $. I must be missing something

Comment: you're forgetting the extra transpose on the second term

Comment: Thanks, and why is the derivative of  $-Y^TX\vec{\beta}$ with regard to beta equal to $-X^TY$ ?  Shouldn't it be : $-Y^TX$ ?

Comment: That is because machine learning is a mockery of mathematics, with contradictory and confusing conventions.

Comment: Fair point but is there a mistake or am I missing something ?

Comment: The answer is in the first sentence of my first comment. They sometimes do and sometimes do not use the convention the derivative is the transpose what it actually is. I don't just say words to waste space, I promise.

Comment: Oh okay so you meant that the whole 2nd term was, because written horizontally, considered as transpose of the actual derivative. I got it. This is indeed a bit confusing. Thank you for your patient help.

Comment: You're welcome! If it helps, I recommend sticking with a convention where the partials are the correct derivative (derivative w.r.t. a column vector is a row vector and vice versa) and the "gradient" is the transpose of the partial. This will get you through 50% of machine learning material hassle free but more importantly leave you able to actually compute things.

Comment: I'll remember it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please specify the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$.