# Gradient of norm

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

How can I compute the gradient of f(x)= $||Ax-b||_{R^{-1}}^2$ I'm also confused about how to compute the gradient of g(x) = $||y-Ax||$ using the chain rule.

I think the first step to take the gradient of g(x) would be
$\nabla(g(x)) = \frac{d(y-Ax)^\top}{dx}(y-Ax)+ \frac{d(y-Ax)}{dx}(y-Ax)^\top$. However, I'm unsure of how to take the derivative of (y-Ax) or the derivative of $(y-Ax)^\top$. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I derived the gradient in the case $R = I$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4093964/40119 The derivation can be adapted to your problem by taking $g(u) = \| u \|_{R^{-1}}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that $D(||x||^2)(x) = 2x^T$, where $D$ denotes the (total) dervative. The gradient is the transpose of the derivative. Also $D(Ax + b)(x) = A$. By the chain rule, $Df(x) = 2(Ax - b)^TA$. Thus $\nabla f(x) = Df(x)^T = 2A^T(Ax - b)$.

To compute $Dg(x)$, it will be helpful to first compute $D(||x||)(x)$. By the chain rule, \begin{align}
D(||x||)(x) &= D(\sqrt{||x||^2})(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(||x||^2)^{-1/2}2x^T \\
&= \frac{1}{||x||}x^T.
\end{align}
Now the derivative of $g$ is easy to obtain using the chain rule: $Dg(x) = \frac{1}{||y - Ax||}(y - Ax)^T(-A)$. So $\nabla g(x) = -\frac{1}{||y - Ax||}A^T(y - Ax)$.

Edit: I guess you meant $f(x) = (Ax - b)^TR^{-1}(Ax - b)$. To compute the derivative of $f$, it is convenient to first compute the derivative of $q(x) = x^TBx$, where $B$ is any matrix. For any vector $y$ we have
\begin{align}
q(x + y) &= (x + y)^TB(x + y) \\
&= (x^T + y^T)(Bx + By) \\
&= x^TBx + x^TBy + y^TBx + y^TBy \\
&= q(x) + x^TBy + (Bx)^Ty + O(|y|^2) \\
&= q(x) + x^T(B + B^T)y + O(|y|^2).
\end{align}
Hence $Dq(x) = x^T(B + B^T)$. Note with $B = R^{-1}$, $f(x) = q(Ax - b)$. Hence by chain rule, $$Df(x) = (Ax - b)^T(R^{-1} + (R^{-1})^T)A.$$ Taking the transpose gives $$\nabla f(x) = A^T((R^{-1})^T + R^{-1})(Ax - b).$$

Comment: Thank you! I think for the gradient of f(x) we need to take the $R^{-1}$ into account. If the derivative of (Ax+b)(x) =A then does that mean the gradient of (Ax+b)(x) = $A^{\top}$? Since the $||x||_{2}^{2} = x^{\top}x $ wouldn't the derivative be a scalar since $x^{\top}x$  results in a 1x1 matrix or in other words a scalar?

Comment: @MushMush 1. What does the $R^{-1}$ subscript mean? 2. The derivative $Df$ (aka Jacobian) applies for $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. At each $x$ in the domain of $f$, $Df(x) \colon \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ is a linear map, which is represented by a $m \times n$ matrix. The gradient only applies when $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and is defined as $\nabla f(x) := Df(x)^T$. So the gradient of $f(x) = Ax + b$ isn't defined unless $A = v^T$ for some vector $v$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, and in this case the gradient is indeed $v$.

Comment: $||−||_{2}^{^{−1}} = (Ax-b)^{\top}R^{-1}(Ax-b)$. R is a nxn matrix. A is a nxm matrix. b is a mx1 vector. Are you saying it's not possible to find the gradient of this norm? I know the least squares problem is supposed to correspond to normal equations and I was told that I could find the normal equations that the least square problem corresponded to by taking the gradient.

Comment: @MushMush The function you wrote is a scalar valued function, so it has a gradient. I updated the answer to include the computation for $\nabla f$.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of the norm squared is just $\nabla||x||^2=\nabla (x_1^2+\dots +x_n^2)=(\partial/\partial x_1 (x_1^2+\dots +x_n^2),\dots,\partial/ \partial x_n (x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2))=(2x_1,\dots ,2x_n)=2 (x_1,\dots,x_n) $.

So substitute  $y-Ax $ for $x $.

Comment: Gradient is a vector field, not a scalar one.

Comment: Oops.   It's been a while.  @MostafaAyaz

Comment: It'll be OK with a slight edit :)

Answer (score 0):

For a vector $a$,

$$\nabla(a\cdot x)=a$$

because if you expand the dot product and differentiate on a component $x_i$, what remains is the component $a_i$ of $a$.

Now seeing the matrix $a$ as an aggregation of column vectors,
$$\nabla(Ax)=A.$$

From this,

$$\nabla\|Ax-b\|^2=\nabla((Ax-b)^T(Ax-b))
\\=\nabla((Ax)^TAx-b^T(Ax)-(Ax)^Tb+b^2)
\\=\nabla((Ax)^TAx-b^T(Ax)-(Ax)^Tb+b^Tb)
\\=\nabla(Ax)^TAx+(Ax)^T\nabla(Ax)-2A^Tb
\\=A^TAx+(Ax)^TA-2A^Tb
\\=2A^T(Ax)-2A^Tb.$$

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how you got that this equation is equal: $∇(()^\top−^\top()−()^\top+^\top) =∇()^\top+()^\top∇()−2^\top$ This equation $^\top+()^\top−2^\top=2^\top()−2^\top$ indicates that $x^{\top}A^{\top}A = A^{\top}Ax$ correct? How do you know $x^{\top}A^{\top}A = A^{\top}Ax$?